# Execute Stored Procedure with Parameters in python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, parameters, pyodbc

I am trying to execute a stored procedure but it is getting complicated, my code in python is:

```
import pyodbc as pyodbc

import pandas as pd

server = 'server'

bd = 'bd'

usuario = 'usuario'

contrasena = 'contrasena'

try:
      conexion = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC DRIVER 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+bd+';UID='+usuario+';PWD='+contrasena, autocommit=True)
      cursor=conexion.cursor()

      print('Sucess')

except:

      print('error trying to connect')


sql = "exec Usp_UltimosRQGeneradosxUsuario @Usuario=?"

params = ('Felix')

cursor.execute(sql, params)

cursor.commit()
```

I don't get any errors, I would like to know what I am missing in order to see the data.

My stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_UltimosRQGeneradosxUsuario]  
@Usuario varchar(50)


as
BEGIN

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RequestorID ORDER BY RequestDate Desc) As Row#,
    Company, RequestorID Usuario, ReqNum, StatusType,RequestDate Fecha
INTO #Temporal
From ReqHead with (nolock)
WHERE (StatusType = 'O' OR StatusType = 'P')
    AND RequestDate <= GETDATE()
    AND RequestorID = @Usuario
    AND Company = 'TEC01'
    Order By RequestorID, RequestDate Desc

SELECT MAX (Row#) NFila, Company, Usuario, ReqNum, StatusType, Fecha FROM #Temporal 
WHERE Row# <= 5
GROUP BY Row#, Company, Usuario, ReqNum, StatusType, Fecha
ORDER BY Usuario, NFila Asc
```

Thanks

---

```
sql = """SET NOCOUNT ON; exec Usp_UltimosRQGeneradosxUsuario @Usuario=?"""
params = ('Felix',)
cursor.execute(sql, params)
cursor.fetchall()
cursor.commit()
conexion.close()
print("connection terminated")
```

I changed this last part with the changes that were indicated in the comments, but it still does not bring me the data, but it does not generate an error

Comment: Your favorite search engine has millions of hits for the basics of using parameters with python. Just search for "how to use parameters with python".

Comment: You need `params = ('Felix',)`.  The substitution thing needs to be a sequence.  One of the quirks of Python is that `(x)` is not a one-element tuple.  It's just a parenthesized `x`.  You need `(x,)`.

Comment: Hello, I made the change params = ('Felix',) but it still does not generate the data. :C

sql = "exec Usp_UltimosRQGeneradosxUsuario @Usuario=?"

params = ('Felix',)

cursor.execute(sql, params)

cursor.commit()

Comment: Start your stored procedure with `SET NOCOUNT ON;` so the `SELECT … INTO` does not emit a row count that will complicate things. Then you can use `cursor.fetchall()` to retrieve the rows after you `.execute()` the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got to correct the error in this way:

```
sql = """SET NOCOUNT ON; exec Usp_UltimosRQGeneradosxUsuario @Usuario=?"""
params = ('Felix',)
cursor.execute(sql, params)
result=cursor.fetchall()
cursor.commit()
conexion.close()
print(result)
print("Conexion Finalizada")
```